# Error with redirecting to other URL in Php

Tags: php, session, redirect, deprecated

I am a java programmer and new to Php. I am trying to design a login form in Php where I am checking the user id and password from database.If the read data is correct i want to redirect the user to welcome.php page.Below is my code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
include("config.php");
session_start();
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
$myusername=addslashes($_POST['username']); 
$mypassword=addslashes($_POST['password']);
$sql="SELECT rid FROM register WHERE rname='$myusername' and rpass='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
@$active=$row['active'];
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count==1)
{
session_register("myusername");
$_SESSION['login_user']=$myusername;
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_WARNING | E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
flush();
header('Location: http://localhost/login/welcome.php');
die('should have redirected by now');
}
else 
{
$error="Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
}
}
?>
```

But after submitting the form with correct id and password I am getting errors as shown below:

[image]

I tried many solutions such as deleting empty spaces,using ob_start() etc but in vain.

Comment: Have you tried removing error display? header('Location:...') only works if there has been no output at all (errors count as output)

Comment: Initially I tried that way but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use simple solution.

In your case, you have some header send than you can't modified.

The simple solution is to send some script code;

```
echo "<script language=\"javascript\">
window.location.assign('http://localhost/login/welcome.php')</script>";
```

Have a nice day.

François

Answer (score 3):

you should use the following method to register variable in session:

```
$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
```

do not use `session_register("myusername");` as it's not supported anymore

Comment: My bad that was a typo left unedited.What about other error which says header already sent.

Comment: @user2125727 the other error occurs because the first error displayed. It will disappear once you remove `session_register`

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need your *flush()*? Maybe try to embrace your header with die by

```
die(header('Location: ...'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if there is any difference in charset between login.php and config.php. I had cases where a difference in charset caused weird output when performing an include.

Comment: This is more like a comment, since the question already has an accepted answer.